# Height:100% not working despite being applied to html, body, and all wrap elements

Tags: css, height

I've been struggling with this height:100% issue for a while now. You'd think it would be rather straightforward. Just make sure all wrapper elements and html, body have height:100% but no matter what i do the containers do not extend to the bottom of the page. Not using any floats here either. I have to be missing something obvious but I've been unable to solve it so far.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/KfjGU/14/

Comment: What browser(s) are you having this problem in?

Comment: ok, here's the solution I went with. The .pagewrap still does not extend to the bottom and scales to the size of the content, but it'll do for now: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/KfjGU/20/

Comment: I guess that is not what you originally wanted, exactly.  BUT, I think it looks very professional.  And, in the end, does not suffer from any functionality problems over what you originally want (exactly 100%).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "height:100%" from the body and it will work as you expect it to. There is no need for that restriction.

Comment: Actually, that defeats the purpose of getting the UI to extend to the bottom of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/KfjGU/19/